# RSS Feed is giving error in cloud

Tags: asp.net, rss

In my C# asp.net 3.5 application I am using RSS Feed to get current updates of my website. Its working fine and when we subscribe the feed also its updating the data as needed. Now our application is deployed in cloud. There also this RSS feed is opening and showing the data. But When I say Subscribe to this feed Its giving diagnose error page saying Normailization error occured and can not display the page. Let me know how to work with RSS feed in cloud environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check that your mime type is correct. Should be application/rss+xml

Comment: Is it the content type. In my application I gave that as application/xml. Is there any difference with respect to the behaviour of rss feed in the cloud . That subscription is working fine in local.